# Can i use hard or symbolic links on a DVD which needs to be Mac and Windows readable?

Tags: dvd, symbolic-link, hardlink

I'm producing a DVD and want to try to save some space to fit it onto a single-layer disk rather than dual-layer.  There are a lot of repeated files on there and it occurred to me that I could have a "canonical" example of each of them in a special folder and then just link all of the others to that, and thus save space.

Is this actually possible?  I know how to make symbolic links on Mac (where the disk is burned), but I don't know if they're going to work when they're read back off disk, or whether it will actually just copy the file onto the disk when burning anyway, or something else.

Obviously I could find some of this out by experiment, wasting a lot of blank disks in the process, but thought I'd ask here first.

EDIT:  I'm burning the dvd in the terminal on a mac using `hdiutil` to build the iso and to burn it to disk.

Answer (score 1):

Symbolic and hard links are possible with most of the DVD formats that are readable on Macs and Windows. However, some DVD authoring applications support all links, while others seem to ignore hard links in particular.

Most Mac DVD authoring applications have an option to create a disc image rather than immediately burning a DVD. Use this feature to test whether links are preserved. Create a disc image, mount it and check the linked files.

Symbolic links seem to be well supported. Hard links are sometimes ignored, depending on the application and the DVD format that's used.

Some applications do not recognize alias files created with the OS X Finder. Symbolic links, created with the `ln -s` command in Terminal are most compatible with discs meant for both Mac and Windows.

Comment: Thanks @creidhne - i'll add some info about how i'm burning it in an edit to my question.